# Send POST request to apache server with htaccess using WebClient

Tags: c#, php, post, webclient

I've got a problem with sending POST request to the apache server with htaccess using WebClient (I've tryed to using HttpRequest as well as WebRequest but it had the same result).
I've got the following example from vendor on PHP:

```
$soap = curl_init(url);
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$XML = file_get_contents("test.xml");
$request = <<<XML
$XML
XML;
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($request)));
curl_setopt($soap, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
$response = curl_exec($soap);
curl_close($soap);
```

My version on C# is:

```
public static string Post(string login, string password, string url, string content) {
    var result = String.Empty;
    var uri = new Uri(url);

    using (var client = new WebClient()) {
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password);

        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/xml";
        result = client.UploadString(uri, content);
    }

    return result;
}
```

When I run the program I've got an exception with 400 error (bad request). I've sniff the request using Fiddler2 and found the following error message: *"Request header field is missing ':' separator"*
**Can anyone help me found what is wrong in the request and why a server reject the request?**

P.S: Request header

```
POST http://production.is.topdelivery.ru/tests/xmlGate/index.php HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Authorization: Basic YmFiYWR1OmJhYmFkdXBhc3M=
Host: production.is.topdelivery.ru
Content-Length: 1617
Expect: 100-continue
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this ?  I have the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case following code works properly

```
private string post(string content)
{
    var result = String.Empty;
    var uri = new Uri(_url);

    WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "text/xml";

    String encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("user:pass"));
    req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

    using (var s = req.GetRequestStream())
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(s, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        sw.Write(content);
    }
    using (var s = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(s, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    };
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me.  I was having an issue with a newer release of Apache not seeing the credentials even though there was no issue with an older version.  I changed

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password);
```

to

```
String encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("user:pass"));
    req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

and it worked!

Thank you.